# Can't type back tick (grave accent) on windows 10

Tags: windows

I have language support installed for German and English (default) on my computer. I cant type the back tick on my English keyboard but i can type the tilde ~ when i press shift. If i switch to the German keyboard the key works with shift and without it.

Comment: Which [keyboard layout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/windows-keyboard-layouts#)?

Comment: @JosefZ English is my default and the back tick wont work on it, German is my secondary but i currently have it disabled

Comment: Have you got English or English International installed?

Comment: [Why do I have to press the key 4 times to get a '\`' symbol?](//superuser.com/a/888199)

Comment: [Why I have to press keys two times to get the ^ or ´ or \` symbol in Windows 7 and how can I fix it?](//superuser.com/q/890624)%c2%b4-or-symbol-in-windows-7-an

Comment: @DavidPostill I have en-US